# Creating a table in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I am fairly new to LaTeX and creating tables. I was wondering if there was a way to create a table that looks like this:

```
                | Method 1      |           

Threshold       |P  |Z  |W      |

value1          | value |value  |value |

value2          | value |value  |value  |
```

This looks bad the way I typed it because I am not sure how to do it. Threshold is its own column then method one is the title of the next column and beneath that there are 3 evaluation metrics in the column of method 1 then all of the values.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like an easy job for [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) (aligning of the numbers) and [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) (design of table, avoiding vertical rules, see the [manual of `booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/booktabs/booktabs.pdf)).

Also, take a look at the [`siunitx` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) and the [siunitx](/questions/tagged/siunitx) tag as this package has a lot of options and possibilities to not only typeset numbers in tables.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3}
\begin{tabular}{l S S S[table-format=1.5] }
    \toprule
    Threshold & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Method 1} \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
              & {$P$} & {$Z$} & {$W$}        \\ \midrule
    Value 1   & 0.125 & 2.635 & 3.14159      \\
    Value 2   & 1.571 & 0.123 & 2.71828      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I would have used a `\multirow` for the threshold cell in order to vertically center it, since it is the header of the Values column.

Comment: Oh yes thank you this is precisely what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: The only thing I'd change is to replace `\cmidrule{2-4}` with `\cmidrule(l){2-4}`. This would shorten the left-hand end of the rule a small bit, making for a more "open" look of the table.